# Method to find group associated with a target variable

Tags: feature-selection, k-means

The business question that I am trying to answer is: what group(s) of people have the highest chance of default? The features that I have are income, debt to income ratio, fico, etc. How do I find the right group (assuming that I want to cut ~5 percent of the population).

This is an easy exercise when I only consider 1 or 2 dimensions at once. But less so when I want a combination of features at various touch points. I can either bucket the variables or treat them as continuous variables.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What kind of variable "chance of default" is? How was it measured?